# Mock Business Layers Project in .NET

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, xunit

I am facing an issue to Mock Business Layer in my test project. The project is well stabled and **do not uses** any modern patterns like (DI, IoC etc..), however application uses common oops concepts (inheritance, object creation etc..). so in my project case I have following case scanerio.

0. xUnit Test Project
1. CustomerBLL Project
2. BaseBLL Project (Which a referenct of BLL Project)

see the following diagram to get more clearity.
[image]

Please have look following code that I am using for thesting and whats worng in it, and also let me know what is the best way to Mock **BaseBLL** class.

**Lib: BaseBLL -> Classs**

```
    public class BaseBLL
    {
        public string _connectionString = "";
        public BaseBLL()
        {
            _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Lib: CustomerBLL -> CustomerClass**

```
    public class CustomerBLL : BaseBLL
    {
        public string CustomerDetails(string id)
        {
            return "data";
        }
    }
```

**Test Project**

```
public class CustomerUnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetCustomerDetailsNagativeTest()
    {
        // ARRANGE            
        Mock<IConfig> _mockConfig = new Mock<IConfig>();
        _mockConfig.Setup(x => x.ConnectionString).Returns("DB-Connection");
        BaseBLL baseBll = new BaseBLL(_mockConfig.Object.ConnectionString);

        var _customerBLL = new Mock<CustomerBLL>
        {
            CallBase = false
        };

        // ACT
        _customerBLL.Setup<string>(x => x.CustomerDetails("-1")).Returns("0");

        // ASSERT
        Assert.Equal("0", _customerBLL.Object.CustomerDetails("-1"));
    }
```

}

Please let me know how to follow correct approach to follow test this, in my case I am getting following error:

While asserting I am getting error :

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null.*

Comment: If you're writing an unit test why are you mocking the connection string instead of mocking the database itself?

Comment: because of calling to CustomerDetails method that time, BaseBLL get called and CustomerDetails method is depended on db. So that I am trying to mock.

Comment: If you're writing unit tests, you should mock the database itself, which means you could basically mock your repositories. If you want the database to be part of the test, then you should write an integration test, and you shouldn't mock the connection string. Instead, you should provide a test database. I strongly suggest you make this refactor in your code, and isolate the classes that access the database. You'll save a huge amount of coding time